# How to solve deployment error on shinnyappsio?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to deploy my dashboard from Rstudio IDE by clicking Publish, but it returned me below error message:

> Error in inferAppPrimaryDoc(appPrimaryDoc = appPrimaryDoc, appFiles =
>   appFiles,  :    Application mode static requires at least one
>   document. Calls:  ... withStatus -> force -> bundleApp ->
>   inferAppPrimaryDoc Execution halted

When I checked my shinyappsio dashboard, the apps was uploaded there but when clicked the url it showed 202 not found.

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Create a new app.R file in a separate directory with all dependent files, copy paste the r-script and then re-publish.

Rstudio > File > New File > Shiny Web App

Comment: This seemed to work but I am confused about the rules. When you work through the RStudio GUI you check the files that need to be uploaded but it it fails to identify which one is which or so is the error message about. Then I tried putting them in a separate folder as described here and the deployment went well!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 1 file, you need to rename your file and change it to app.R