# Why do I get an error when deploying a shiny app?

Tags: r, deployment, shiny, shinyapps

When I try to publish my ShinyApp with shinyapps.io,
I keep getting the following error message:  'Application mode static requires at least one document'.

Here are some of the fixes, I've implemented:

1. create a different directory with all dependent files and a copy of the R-script.
2. re-created custom functions from my local environment within the app

Furthermore, in 'read.csv' I refer to the files directly without specifying the directory, in case this might be the culprit.
Do you have any idea, what the issue might be?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53390180/how-to-solve-deployment-error-on-shinnyappsio)?

Comment: @NiklasvMoers Yes I have but with a normal R-script instead of an app.R file. Now I was able to upload the app. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it works when I use the "publish" button in RStudio but not using the `deployApp()` function.

Not sure what is the reason of this.